# Which version of MySQL supports CUBE?

Tags: mysql, sql, cube

To my knowledge, MySQL doesn't support `CUBE`, but only supports `ROLLUP`.  However, when I try to execute the following query (with `CUBE`):

`select ifnull(CountryCode,'total') as Country_Code, ifnull(Name,CountryCode) as Name ,sum(Population) from City GROUP BY CountryCode, NAME with CUBE;`

I get the following error message:

`ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'CUBE'`.

Regarding the error message, do any versions of MySql support `CUBE`, or was `CUBE` removed from a previous version of MySQL?

Comment: Unfortunately, **NONE**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though `CUBE` is not yet supported by MySQL.  However, it is supported by Oracle and SQLServer (and possibly others).